# Swift 3 - Use of unresolved identifier 'Static'

Tags: ios

I am following [this example](https://github.com/Clean-Swift/CleanStore) to implement clean architecture in my `iOS` app.

```
class CreateOrderConfigurator
{
  private static var __once: () = {
      //ERROR - use of unresolved identifier 'Static'
      Static.instance = CreateOrderConfigurator()
    }()


  // MARK: Object lifecycle

  class var sharedInstance: CreateOrderConfigurator
  {
    struct Static {
      static var instance: CreateOrderConfigurator?
      static var token: Int = 0
    }

    _ = CreateOrderConfigurator.__once

    return Static.instance!
  }

  // MARK: Configuration

  func configure(_ viewController: CreateOrderViewController)
  {
    let router = CreateOrderRouter()
    router.viewController = viewController

    let presenter = CreateOrderPresenter()
    presenter.output = viewController

    let interactor = CreateOrderInteractor()
    interactor.output = presenter

    viewController.output = interactor
    viewController.router = router
  }
}
```

I get an error saying `use of unresolved identifier 'Static'`. How do I solve this?

PS : I am new to iOS and Swift 3.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A singleton is very simple in Swift

Replace

```
private static var __once: () = {
      //ERROR - use of unresolved identifier 'Static'
      Static.instance = CreateOrderConfigurator()
    }()


  // MARK: Object lifecycle

  class var sharedInstance: CreateOrderConfigurator
  {
    struct Static {
      static var instance: CreateOrderConfigurator?
      static var token: Int = 0
    }

    _ = CreateOrderConfigurator.__once

    return Static.instance!
  }
```

with

```
static let sharedInstance = CreateOrderConfigurator()
```